# TeXWorks: Putting Asymptote packages in a different directory

Tags: asymptote

I'm trying to make LaTeX files using custom Asymptote packages, in particular olympiad.asy, and I'm wondering if there's a way I can store all of these custom packages in one spot. Right now I'm putting the olympiad.asy file into the same directory as the LaTeX file I'm compiling, and this works nicely, but I'd rather not have to include olympiad.asy in the directory every single time I want to use it. Is there a way I can make TeXWorks look in different directories for asymptote packages?

Comment: An ad hoc fix would be to have a soft link to the file you want to include. This way you would have them in a tar ball if you ever give the files to someone else.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation of Asymptote (section 2.5 *Search path* in the file `asymptote.pdf`), supplementary Asymptote modules are searched in this order here:

- the current directory of the .asy or .tex file to compiling
- in directory listed in `ASYMPTOTE_DIR` environment variable
- in directory listed in `ASYMPTOTE_HOME` environment variable
- in Asymptote directory created on its installation

More details (differences between UNIX and MSDOS) in the .pdf cited above.

For example, on my OS X (aka UNIX) installation, I have made this in Terminal (to avoid using the hidden directory `.asy` in the user home directory) :

Go to the root of the current user (if necessary):

```
cd ~
```

Open the (invisible) file `.bash_profile` with `nano` utility:

```
nano .bash_profile
```

Adding this line:

```
export ASYMPTOTE_HOME=/Users/my_name/Library/ASY
```

Save with `ctrl+O`, confirm file name with `ENTER` key, then exit with `ctrl+X`.

Open new Terminal window (or restart Terminal) and verify your change with `echo $ASYMPTOTE_HOME` or with `printenv`.

With this, I add Asymptote modules in `/Users/my_name/Library/ASY` instead the hidden `/Users/my_name/.asy/` directory.